# Problem with GET method: requests showing wrong data

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, request

I have a problem in requests which just happens in GET methods and POST methods works fine. When I send a GET requests it shows me wrong data; This is my route:

```
Route::get('/gettest',function ( \Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
var_dump($request->all());
//var_dump(input::get('id'));

});
```

This is my request URL:

```
https://gfects.com/gettest?id=2
```

and I get this response:

```
array(1) { ["url"]=> string(7) "gettest" } null
```

I tried many things, I just can't find a solution.

Comment: lets see the controller

Comment: Why are you trying to “work around” the routing system? Why is this not set up as `Route::get('gettest/{id}'` to begin with, so that the URL `https://gfects.com/gettest/2` maps onto it …?

Comment: @julius-fasema problem is happening in all place including contollers
but this is a small test Route for findout why this is heppening

Comment: @04fs i need it in this way because im trying to add Google auth in my site and it returns liks this

Comment: why not query the record and display using the  normal laravel query method instead of var_dump

Comment: @julius-fasema it in this way because im trying to add Google auth in my site and it returns url is liks this

Comment: try https://gfects.com/gettest?id=2, $request->input('id') will return only id

Comment: @04FS the question displays an error in a minimal way. A GET variable doesn't show up on the `$request`. What does it matter if he calls it `id` or `page` or `token`? Not every URI variable has to be passed to "routing system".

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of var_dump($request->all()); , use dd($request->all());

Answer (score -1):

Try `request()->input('id');` instead of `request()->all()`.

[input() method definition](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L206)

[all() method definition](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L182)

As you can see, `all()` does not check the query parameters.

Comment: hi there
i try that but it return me null 
and i'm confused about this